# populate table with initial data

Tags: django, django-models, django-fixtures

I want to prepopulate some tables with initial data and also modify certian fields. Im currently doing this by writing custom management commands and populating database using python manage.py  .
Recently i read about fixtures and came to know its used for the same purpose .Which is the right way to do this and why or why not this should be done using the management commands?

Example code in management/commands/init_test_data.py

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Initializes test data'

    @transaction.atomic
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        __location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(
            os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
        fname = os.path.join(__location__, 'init_test_data.json')
        with open(fname) as f:
            parsed = json.load(f)
        for tenant in parsed.get('tenants'):
            self.create_tenant(tenant)

    def create_tenant(self, tenant):
        tenant_obj = Tenant()
        tenant_obj.name = tenant["name"]
        tenant_obj.subdomain = tenant["subdomain"]
        tenant_obj.identifier = tenant["identifier"]
        tenant_obj.save()
        for org in tenant.get('organisations'):
            self.create_org(tenant_obj, org)
        admin_email = "sysadmin_" + tenant_obj.name + "@exza.com"
        admin_roles = ["tenant_system_admin", "tenant_admin"]
        self.create_user(None, tenant_obj, admin_email, admin_roles, True, True)
        for asset in tenant.get('assets'):
            self.create_dummy_asset(tenant_obj, asset.get('name'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixtures is indeed the way to go to set some initial data. If you want to perform some more complex operations you can use custom migrations (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/)

Comment: this is also not only test data.initial data shoulf be there for the site to work since im implementing multiple tenantcy

Comment: With management commands you need to make sure you execute this in your deployment or on a new setup. With migrations you know that this will always be executed when you run the migration.

Comment: i see. also fixtures will execute automatically?

Comment: Fixtures wont be running automatically so you need a data migration for that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations